# Why Debian-based distro's don't have newest Qt version?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-mint, repository, qt

I am wondering why distributions based on Debian, like Ubuntu or Mint don't have newest Qt - 5.5 - version in repository. I must download it from page to have 5.5, there is only 5.2 in repo.

I know that Debian has stable, testing and unstable releases, but distro's like Linux Mint have a much newer versions of many packages. Why this one is a little obsolete?

Qt 5.2.0 was released **over 2 years ago**, 5.2.1 - 1 year and 10 months ago.
It looks for sufficient time that the next version should already be in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect any particular distribution to have the absolute latest versions of any package, unless it's a rolling distribution specifically based on Debian Unstable (sid).

The newest packages usually get into Debian Unstable (sid) first.

Ubuntu is based on Debian Testing, so is supposed to have more stable, better tested packages.

Linux Mint (their "main" version) is based off of the latest LTS release of Ubuntu (older than the regular Ubuntu), plus a few select updated packages. I *think* their idea being *"if it ain't broke, don't fix it."*

- [This DistroWatch.com search](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=Linux&category=All&origin=All&basedon=Debian+%28Unstable%29&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&package=All&rolling=Rolling&isosize=All&netinstall=All&status=Active) looks for all Debian Unstable based, rolling release, active distros. Currently there are only 3 hits:

  1. [siduction](http://distrowatch.com/siduction) (69)
     The siduction distribution is a desktop-oriented operating system and live medium based on the "unstable" branch of Debian GNU/Linux. Forked from aptosid in late 2011, siduction offers three separate live media with KDE, LXDE and Xfce desktops. The project also promises regular releases, an open development model, and friendly relationship with its developer and user community.
  2. [Semplice Linux](http://distrowatch.com/semplice) (78)
     Semplice Linux is a simple, fast and lightweight distribution based on Debian's unstable branch. It includes a small collection of up-to-date applications running on top of the Openbox window manager.
  3. [LinuxBBQ](http://distrowatch.com/linuxbbq) (132)
     LinuxBBQ is a multi-purpose operating system based on Debian's "unstable" branch and spiced up with kernels and tools from siduction, Grml and Linux Mint. LinuxBBQ offers different flavours and desktops which are released as "editions" (with no version numbers) and which can be customised and remixed by the user. The individual editions are built to include most major desktop environments (with the exception of GNOME) and there is a special edition offering a choice of no fewer than 53 window managers - everything from aewm to xmonad.

There's 9 based on Debian Tesing, but 69 based on Ubuntu, and 23 based on Ubuntu LTS

---

If you want to manually install the absolute newest packages to your system you're more than welcome to, but you may render your system unstable, and dependencies may become impossible to maintain.